# Non polarized capacitor in schematics

Tags: capacitor

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU1Hi.jpg)I am restoring my Sansui AU 6600 Amplifier. 
[image]
I have taken out all old electrolytic capacitors, and my question is. From the part list for F 2092 capacitors C05 and C06 (10 μF) are listed as BP capacitors and looking at the board diagram I can see that the two capacitor do not have the plus sign, and that is ok. But what I do not understand is that in the schematics, capacitors C15 and C16 (3.3 μF) do not have a plus sign, but in the part list these two are not listed as bipolar capacitors.

Could you please clarify?

[image: Sansui AU 6600 Amplifier]

Comment: Perhaps if you would like people to comment on a schematic and parts list then you would include the schematic and parts list in the question.

Comment: Need a schematic.  Either they're supposed to be bipolar caps and the parts list is in error, or they're supposed to be polarized and Sansui just left that off of the schematic.  With a schematic, it's sometimes possible to tell if you can use a polarized cap, and what direction it needs to point.  Or, just use bipolar caps and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you both for your reply. I did attach a photo from the pdf manual of the board in question , I wonder why you can't see it, I am new to this site, probably i did something wrong (I can see it when I am logged in)  I will try again to attach both photos of the board and the part list. Cheers

Comment: Only the parts list and one photo actually appears.  The other is a link named "enter image description here".

Comment: The schematic is blurry when zoomed in, please try to upload it on another place with high resolution capability.

Comment: ok I will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies to my question.
I actually realized that I had not checked properly the documentation. I sorted out which kind of capacitors I needed by first looking at the board. If there is no plus sign (as in my case) I checked the part list. In may case the BP transistors where not listed as BP but only as Electrolytic capacitor (E.C.) but then looking finally at the schematics I saw that the capacitor is BP. Also the BP is written only on one channel I figured it out that of course the same capacitor on the other channel would be BP as well.
This is my first time that I try to restore an Audio Amplifier so I am more aware of what to do now  thanks to the replies that suggested me to look at the schematics. Thanks again for all the replies. Cheers

Comment: It looks like you found the answer.  Please remember to come back and accept it.  That will properly mark your question as done, and it won't keep floating around as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to assume that they are bipolar.  Looking at the circuit diagram, I see no reason to believe that either terminal is consistently more positive or more negative.  It looks like one side is connected via resistors to ground, while the other could potentially be driven by a transistor between +25V and -25V.

Comment: Thank you for your reply